# create in rails 4 active admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin, strong-parameters

I have a user model and inside active admin i have written like

```
ActiveAdmin.register User do
  controller do

    def permitted_params
       params.require(:user).permit(:username,:email,:password,:password_confirmation,
                           :admin, :locked, :first_name, :last_name, :work_phone, :cell_phone,
                           :cell_carrier, :fax, :temp_password,
                           :active, :company_id, :group_id, role_ids:[])
    end

    def create
      @user = User.new(params[:user])
      if @user.save
        redirect_to admin_users_path
      else
        render :new
      end
    end
  end
end
```

But when ever i am trying to create the user its showing an error like. **ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError - ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError:**
What i am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

Inherited Resources is a little weird with permitted params. You don't actually get to `require` key. You have to pass a hash to the `permit` method.

If you're using the latest version of ActiveAdmin, you should also be able to use the `permit_params` method.

```
ActiveAdmin.register User do
  permit_params :username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation,
                :admin, :locked, :first_name, :last_name, :work_phone, :cell_phone,
                :cell_carrier, :fax, :temp_password,
                :active, :company_id, :group_id, role_ids:[]
  end
end
```

Also, if you are going to override the `create` method, you must use `permitted_params` in place of `params[:user]`, which is most likely the cause of the current error you're getting. It doesn't look like you're actually doing anything special in your custom `create` action, though, so unless you plan to do something more, you should probably just let ActiveAdmin handle the controller actions.